# File IO on a remote Windows system

Tags: perl, file-io

Given a Perl script that can be running on unix or Windows, how can I best read/write to a file on a  windows host? Is there anything similar to [File::Remote](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to mount the remote folder and then use the standard perl functions:

```
use constant W_REMOTE_FOLDER = '\\server\share';
use constant W_LOCAL_FOLDER = 'x:\share\';
use constant L_REMOTE_FOLDER = 'smb://server/share';
use constant L_LOCAL_FOLDER = '/mnt/share/';

my $localfolder = '';

if ($am_i_windows)
{
    system('net use ...');
    $localfolder = W_LOCAL_FOLDER;
}
if ($am_i_linux)
{
    system('mount ...');
    $localfolder = L_LOCAL_FOLDER;
}
die "What am I? if ($localfolder eq '');


open(HANDLE, "$localfolder/$filename");
# read/write (...)
close(HANDLE);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, what do you mean by mounting the remote folder? just to be clear -- the remote windows host is not guaranteed to be running anything nor even have perl installed. wasn't sure if it was possible or not.

Comment: It doesn't need Perl. It needs to have enabled "File and Printer Sharing".
By mounting I mean to make the remote file system available locally. (Unix: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29 || Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300856/en)